# Open pop-up in every 10 minutes time interval in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have trying to open popup on every 10 minuets time interval and close automatically within 15 seconds.

the below code is for popup which is open into click event but i want to open it automatically  10 minuets of  time interval.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[id*=btnPopup]").live("click", function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>

<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
    This is a simple popup
</div>
```

Please help :(

Comment: [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use combination of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) and [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout).

Also You need to Initialize dialog outside the click handler of button.

*code*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Initialize dialog
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            Close: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });


    //bind click handler
    $("[id*=btnPopup]").live("click", function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });

    //Open dialog
    setInterval(function() {

        $('#dialog').dialog('open');

        //Close after 15 seconds
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
        }, 15000);
    }, 600000);
});
```

Comment: in click event its working fine but Interval in not working sir @Satpal

Comment: @GarimaRawat, Add `autoOpen: false` while Initializing dialog

Comment: One more question please don't mind @Satpal sir, this code is for only one time  open or close , is it possible to do with loop? i mean when popup is close then again its interval continue and open again on the given time ?

Comment: @GarimaRawat, Read docs `setInterval` will open pop-up every `600000` milliseconds (10 mins) for testing reduce the time interval. Also I would recommend  that you should go through the links provide

Comment: but its open 1 time and after close its not open again

Answer (score 3):

Open dialogue via jquery with setInterval and for closing use setTimeout:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('#dialog').dialog('open');
  setTimeout(function(){
     $('#dialog').dialog('close');
  },15000)
},600000);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/92jv0erw/)**

Comment: thanks for the answer @milind but i want to open it every 10 minuets time interval and close automatically within 15 seconds.

Comment: @GarimaRawat: was updating the answer. :)

Comment: @GarimaRawat: see the demo .

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` like this: [fiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/6FGqN/1475/)

After 10 minutes  10 * 60 * 1000 = **600000** (10 mins * 60 seconds per minute * 1000 milliseconds per second.
After 15 minutes (after 15 * 60 * 1000 = **900000** 
HTML

```
<div id="dialog">Your non-modal dialog</div>
<a href="#" id="open">Open dialog</a>
```

JS

```
$('#open').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');    
});    

   jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        open: function(){
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
                jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
            })
        }
    });

setTimeout(function() {      
                  $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    }, 600000);    

setTimeout(function() {  
   $('#dialog').dialog('close');
    }, 900000);
```

Comment: This wont work...
She wants to open it every 10 minutes and close it automatically within 15 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Below code must solve your issue. Its working fine for me.

```
$("#[Your Div Id]").dialog({
    width: 400
 });


setInterval(function(){
  $('#[Your Div Id]').dialog('open');
  setTimeout(function(){
     $('#[Your Div Id]').dialog('close');
  },15000) // 15 Seconds
},600000); // 10 mins
```

Hope this works.